# MSFT Word window won't resize in office 2011

Tags: ms-office, microsoft, windows

My MSFT Word document won't resize, beyond a point.  I'm trying to compared multiple documents on the screen at once.  Thus, I'm trying to shrink them to fit on my screen.

The window doesn't shrink past four inches or so length.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. This is vague, please add screenshots or more details...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure no panes are open in the sidebar (Contents, Reviewing, Advanced Search).

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like strange instructions but they worked in other occasions.

Use system Preferences and change screen resolution.

Then change it back.

That should work, since Word got stuck with recognizing screen resolution.